# Numbers: how do I create a column with a sequence of times?

Tags: numbers, automation

In Numbers, I would like to create a column with automatically generated cells to create a timetable with each hour and each half hour.

I create a new document, type in "7:30 AM" and then in the cell below I type in "8:00 AM" then I drag downwards from the first cell, but it doesn't work, it replaces "8:00 AM" by "8:30 AM" but I only want 30 mns increments...

[image]

I tried changing the cell format to "date and time" but it just erases whatever I typed and replaces it by today's date and time or random dates and times...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [njboot's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204297/120171), If you wish to drag and apply the ½ hour increments *without entering a formula*,  be sure to select **Both** cells before dragging down the yellow dot.  This will copy the pattern down (or across, for that matter.)

[image]

[image]

---

#### *Edit:*

If you want to use a formula:

Use Duration:

`DURATION(weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

Using *Duration* one can then adjust the increments later on affecting all cells with one simple change.  For example, suppose you wish to change it to 15 minute increments or 2 hour or 25 minutes.  This can be accomplished using a dynamic formula to allow for greater flexibility in your solution.

One could add a new table (or use hidden cells or whatever tickles one's fancy) to create an area where a number can be added that will change the increments universally.

#### Create Duration formula:

[image: Duration Formula]

Notice that **Hours** and **Minutes** are tied to cells that can be adjusted without changing the formula.

[image: Formula to increment time]

#### Then, after dragging down the formula, just change the increments when desired.

[image: 30 minute]
[image: 15 minute]

Answer (score 2):

The formula syntax in Numbers is actually less intuitive and more stubborn than Excel IMO. Nevertheless, to create time intervals:

1. In the first cell, say `B2`, type `8:00 AM`
2. In the following cell, type `=B2+"30m"`

   [image]
3. *Now*, drag down:

   [image]
4. Voilà:

   [image]

Comment: Awesome! But I think you mean "Voilà" :)

Comment: @fabriced Sì! colpa mia :)